# Rotate/Shift a list in Dartlang?

Tags: dart

Is there a better/faster way in Dart to rotate a list?

```
List<Object> rotate(List<Object> l, int i) {
  i = i % l.length;

  List<Object> x = l.sublist(i);
  x.addAll(l.sublist(0, i));

  return x;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the issue if a empty list is provided (IntegerDivisionByZeroException), it looks good to me.

Comment: Actually it is a `shift` not a `rotate`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could be simplified a bit

```dart
List<Object> rotate(List<Object> list, int v) {
  if(list == null || list.isEmpty) return list;
  var i = v % list.length;
  return list.sublist(i)..addAll(list.sublist(0, i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `shift` instead of `rotate` you can simply use the `removeAt` function:

```dart
List<int> list = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
int firstElement = list.removeAt(0);
print(list); // [ 2, 3 ]
print(firstElement); // 1
```

From the docs:

> Removes the object at position [index] from this list.
>
> This method reduces the length of this by one and moves all later objects down by one position.
>
> Returns the removed value.
>
> The [index] must be in the range 0 ≤ index < length. The list must be growable.

[Here](https://github.com/dartist/node_shims/blob/master/lib/src/js.dart) are some more useful JS shims.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an extension to use it anywhere with null safety.

```dart
extension RotateList<T> on List<T>{
  List<T> rotate(int rotate){
    if(isEmpty) return this;
    var index = rotate % length;
    return sublist(index)..addAll(sublist(0, index));
  }
}
```